# Обясните пожалуйста почему тут результат 10?

Tags: javascript

Вот код

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  setTimeout(function () { 
    console.log(i); 
  }, 0); 
}
```

результатом его выполнения будет 10 раз выведено число 10. Вопрос почему? И тут же следующий вопрос:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  setTimeout(function () { 
    console.log(i); 
  }, 0); 
}
```

Почему в этом случае будет поледовательно выведено от 0 до 9? Я немогу понять в чем разница?

Это не дубликат вопроса. Потому что:
Я думал что когда передаешь 0 в setTimeout эта функция выволнится немеделенно при каждой итерации. И я так и не понимаю почему в случае с let функция начинает выполняться при каждой итерации а не 10 раз подряд после цикла.

Comment: `эта функция выволнится немеделенно` - нет. Функция будет помещена в eventLoop и будет выполнена на следующей его итерации, которая, в свою очередь, не запустится, пока поток выполнения занят текущим синхронным кодом.

Comment: В дубликате нет ответа почему `let` работает по-другому. Голосую за переоткрытие. Автору: вы можете прочитать про это здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const . Вкратце: `let` создает новую переменную в каждой итерации цикла (я не могу оформить это в ответе, тк, нельзя писать ответы к закрытым вопросам).

Comment: @Crantisz, в дубликате, как минимум есть ссылка на описание let

Comment: @Grundy и что? Вы прекрасно знаете, что ссылки вместо ответов [не приветствуются на SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Crantisz, не приветствуются ответы состоящие _только_ из ссылок. В данном случае - ответ описывает _все возможные_ варианты решения  проблемы асинхронных функций в цикле, и _в дополнение_ дает ссылки на более подробную информацию.

Comment: @Grundy: этот вариант есть и в этом вопросе. Чего нет, так это объяснения чем он отличается от проблемного.

Comment: Первый коментарий дает ответ на первую часть вопроса - спасибо. Да отличие почему с let работает по другому мне и хотелось бы узнать. Во втром коменте непонятно почему он создает новую переменную на каждой итерации? Ведь тогда она на каждой итерации инициализировалась бы нулем.

Comment: В принципе https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const тут и описано по какой причине лет ведет себя по другому внутри цикла. Спасибо за помощь! Впопрос снят